# Initialising an array in a class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, int

I am writing a class for a stack with 4 elements. Defined like this:

```
// HPStack.h
class HPStack{
public:
        HPStack();
        void push(int x);
        int  pop();
        int  peek();
private:
        int stack[];
};
 // HPStack.cpp
HPStack::HPStack(){
        int stack[4] = {0,0,0,0};
}
// push/pop functions
// ....
int HPStack::peek(){
        return stack[0];
}
```

Then I call it with:

```
int main(){
        HPStack* stack = new HPStack();
        cout << stack->peek() << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

But when I run the `main` function (compiled with g++), it outputs: `137048` when I actually want it to print 0. What is going on here and what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: your local[] in the ctor dies when the ctor completes, hence you are left with the class int stack[] which has garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HPStack::HPStack(){
        int stack[4] = {0,0,0,0};
}
```

Here, `stack` is declared as a local variable. If your class has a member variable also called `stack` then it is not initialized and not visible in the constructor because it has been hidden.

If you want to zero-initialized a member array, you can *value-initialize* it by giving it an explicit empty initializer in the member initializer list.

```
HPStack::HPStack() : stack()
{
}
```

**Edit:** This is an illegal member definition. If you have an array member you must give it a non-zero size:

```
private:
    int stack[];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int stack[4] = {0,0,0,0};
```

is a local variable and goes out of scope once the constructor returns. `stack[]` as a member variable is different from the one present in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
int stack[4] = {0,0,0,0};
```

This creates a *local* stack variable - it's not modifying your *member* stack variable. Change it to:

```
std::fill(stack, stack+4, 0);
```

Or simply:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    stack[i] = 0;
```

Also, your `stack` member variable should be declared like this:

```
int stack[4];
```

Updated code:

```
// HPStack.h
class HPStack{
public:
        HPStack();
        void push(int x);
        int  pop();
        int  peek();
private:
        int stack[4];
};
 // HPStack.cpp
HPStack::HPStack(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
            stack[i] = 0;
}
// push/pop functions
// ....
int HPStack::peek(){
        return stack[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of HPStack you've initialized local array instead of member-array, have you noticed?

Comment: When I compile it with this I get: HPStack.cpp: In constructor 'HPStack::HPStack()':
HPStack.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
HPStack.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before '{' token

Comment: Your code means the the 4th element of the array must be {0, 0, 0, 0} ;)

Comment: That was my mistake, and I fixed it as soon as I noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `int stack[4]` as the member variable of `HPStack`. But in constructor you are doing `int stack[4] = {0,0,0,0};`, the extra `int` here results in a new *local* variable `stack` which hides the original member variable. So when you use `peek` the member variable is uninitialized and you get a garbage value. You need to correct your initialization code, take a look at the `std::fill` method which can fill the already defined array with a given value.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you must dynamically allocate memory for your array.

```
stack = new int[4];
```

Or you can make a static array in your class definition

```
int stack[4];
```

PS: when you use dynamic allocation don't forget to free memory in your destructor:

```
delete[] stack;
```

Comment: I thought the rule was, malloc-free, new-delete.